# React native: how do i disable a button?

Tags: react-native

i currently have a button on my posts page. I want to disable this button if the current user id is equal to the post user id.

I am using Formik to manage my state.

AppButton.js

```
 function AppButton({ title, onPress}) {
 return (
 <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button]} onPress={onPress}>
  <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

SubmitButton.js

```
import { useFormikContext } from "formik";

function SubmitButton({ title }) {
const { handleSubmit } = useFormikContext();
return <AppButton title={title} onPress={handleSubmit}/>;
}
```

Form.js

```
function MessageForm({ post,user }) {
return(
<SubmitButton title="Message"/>
```

PostScreen.js

```
function PostScreen({ route }) {
const post = route.params.post;
const { user } = useAuth();

clg(user.id) // this prints the id of the current user
clg(post.userId) / /this prints the userId of the post

return(
<Form post={post}/>
```

Comment: Pass `disabled=true` for TouchableOpacity

Comment: Ok and where do i set the condition, that if the user id === post user id then set disabled=false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
<SubmitButton title="Message" disabled={user.id === post.userId} />

function SubmitButton({ title, disabled }) {
  const { handleSubmit } = useFormikContext();
  return <AppButton title={title} onPress={handleSubmit} disabled={disabled}/>;
}

function AppButton({ title, onPress, disabled}) {
 return (
   <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button]} onPress={onPress} disabled={disabled} >
     <Text style={styles.text}>{title}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, this worked. thank you. Is there a way if user.id === post.userId and user tried pressing to show an alert message to the user?

Comment: @kd12345 checkout my answer